# Fastlane NoMethodError

Tags: ios, ruby, bundler, apple-m1, fastlane

I have a macbook(2020) with m1 processor and I am using Fastlane to automate the AppStore process. I have a problem since this morning. Every time I execute `bundle exec fastlane` I get this error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.206.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:145:in `map_aliased_tools': undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.206.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:81:in `take_off'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.206.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
```

Here are the versions of the tools I am using:

1. ruby version: 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin21]
2. xcode version: 13.3 (13E113)
3. macos version: 12.3.1

Even though I tried to set up fastlane again using `fastlane init` command it still gives me this error.
What could be causing this issue?

**Update:**
I installed my own ruby using rvm(https://stackify.com/install-ruby-on-your-mac-everything-you-need-to-get-going/) and then used the recommended way of installing fastlane(with bundler) and now I have a similar error.

```
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/fastlane)
cli_tools_distributor.rb:145:in `map_aliased_tools': undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.206.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:81:in `take_off'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.206.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/cli.rb:483:in `exec'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in `with_friendly_errors'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.14/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
from /Users/mehmetbaykar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but it's true all the same: The fact that you have installed the fastlane gem in `/LibraryRuby/Gems` is a _bug_. Before you do anything else you need to _stop_ using the system ruby.

Comment: I uninstalled the fastlane and installed it in the recommended way(with bundler) but still gives me the same error.

Comment: But did you install your own ruby? If you see _the same_ error, you didn't fix what I said to fix.

Comment: what do you mean by "own ruby"?

Comment: "Your own" means a different ruby, belonging to you, personally. If you have to say `sudo` you're doing it wrong. You're using the system's ruby. Don't. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67445580/341994

Comment: I followed your answer and still have the same error.

Comment: Excellent! — I would suggest reverting to an earlier version of fastlane, perhaps

Comment: Yes, you are right! Using an old version of bundler fixed the issue. But still didn’t get what was the real reason behind this error.

Comment: The Fastlane people do introduce bugs every so often. They've made this kind of mistake before! See https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/11468 You should report this as an issue.

Comment: Glad you got it solved! If you hear back from them, you might give an answer to your own question; this could be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20292) for this bug. The issue occurs when you run fastlane without any additional command-line arguments. There are two temporary workarounds:

1. Enable verbose mode: `bundle exec fastlane --verbose`
2. Specify a lane name: `bundle exec fastlane my_lane_name`

Alternatively, you can downgrade to an earlier version of fastlane.